# Android - There is data missing in the database

Tags: android

I modified it like this:

```
public class Bill extends LitePalSupport {
    private int id;
    private double sum;
    private String remarks;
    private Date time;
    private BillClassification classification = new BillClassification("饮食",0);


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public double getSum() {
        return sum;
    }

    public void setSum(double sum) {
        this.sum = sum;
    }

    public String getRemarks() {
        return remarks;
    }

    public void setRemarks(String remarks) {
        this.remarks = remarks;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss");
        String str = formatter.format(time);
        return str;
    }

    public void setTime(){
        time =  new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    public void setClassification(BillClassification classification) {
        this.classification.setClassificationName(classification.getClassificationName());
        this.classification.setClassificationColor(classification.getClassificationColor());
    }

    public BillClassification getClassification() {
        return classification;
    }
}
```

There is no classification before this class, it is added later. Before I added it, there was no problem with the database. But after I added it, I found that there was no classification in the data that was saved successfully.

Class BillClassification:

```
public class BillClassification {
    private String classificationName;
    private int classificationColor;

    public BillClassification(String name, int color){
        classificationName = name;
        classificationColor = color;
    }

    public String getClassificationName(){
        return classificationName;
    }

    public int getClassificationColor(){
        return classificationColor;
    }
    public void setClassificationColor(int classificationColor) {
        this.classificationColor = classificationColor;
    }

    public void setClassificationName(String classificationName) {
        this.classificationName = classificationName;
    }
}
```

Part of my code is as follows :

```
Bill bill = new Bill();
bill.setTime();
bill.setRemarks(remarks.getText().toString());
bill.setSum(getSumByDouble(sum));
bill.setClassification(classification);
Toast.makeText(AddOne.this, "classificationName1:"+bill.getClassification().getClassificationName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
if(bill.save())
    Toast.makeText(AddOne.this, "bill保存成功", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else
    Toast.makeText(AddOne.this, "bill保存失败", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Bill test = LitePal.find(Bill.class, bill.getId());
Toast.makeText(AddOne.this, "remarks:"+test.getRemarks(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

try{
    Toast.makeText(AddOne.this, "classificationName2:"+test.getClassification().getClassificationName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

After running, toast displayed:

classificationName1:(something I input in bill)
 bill保存成功
 remarks:(something I input bill)
classificationName2:(the default value)

And there is no Exception.

Finally, [Litepal](https://github.com/LitePalFramework/LitePal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be any bill object which is not have classification data that u get from `Bill test = LitePal.find(Bill.class, bill.getId());`

you can simply fix it by adding  below thing to BillClassification class

```
private BillClassification classification = new BillClassification("default_name",colorIduwanttosetAsDefault);
```

then there will be no null pointer errors.

But you need to have called this setClassification(.....) for all the bill objects what u create. There can be more null pointer exceptions when you getting some other attribute as well. Therefore u need to **add the proper constructor** to avoid this exception or **set default value** for those attributes way that i show above

Comment: I tried to add setters in my BillClassification, set default value in Bill and modify setClassification(...) like this:  this.classification.setClassificationName(classification.getClassificationName());

Comment: I modified my question, could u give me more help? Thx! Thx!

Comment: What is the error ? same error or different one ? @basketSAMA

Comment: I still cannot store bill classification, what I get from the database is always the default value.

Comment: @basketSAMA It will only set value initially. But when u setBillClassification(...) it should be override.If it still have default value, there may be something wrong with your setBillClassification(..) method call. check it

Comment: I read the guide of LitePal again carefully, and then I tried to change BillClassification to String and int. Finally it worked! Thx!!

Comment: @basketSAMA nice to here it. Happy coding